# How can I assign Event ID = 1 to all log entries written by Serilog.Sinks.EventLog

Tags: serilog

I have the following items in my App.COnfig and I can write to Windows Event Log

```
<add key="serilog:using:EventLog" value="Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog.source" value="MyXYZSource" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:EventLog.manageEventSource" value="true" />
```

However I see junk messages in Eventlog along with my main message:

```
The description for Event ID 43413 from source MyXYZSource cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table
```

I have no idea where the Event ID 43413  came from????

The problem can be easily solved if I can assign Event ID = 1 to events Serilog writes.

Is there an easy way to do that in App.Config that I showed above?